# Use an attribute from an HTML-Tag in Polymer

Tags: css, polymer

I'm using Polymer and I am encountering a Problem. I think there is a good solution, but I still don't have the perfect understanding of polymer.

In my template I get a `dom-repeat` which gets me some `_items`as `item`. `item.name` returns the name of the item, it works just fine. Now I want to use this name to display it in a tooltip, so I call the function `on-mouseenter="_showTooltip"`.

My function looks like this:

```
_showTooltip: function(e) {
    var item = Polymer.dom(e).rootTarget;
    //........here I get Information out of my item to use it in my tooltip and display it
}
```

How can I transfer the information of my original `item` to this function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention or tag which version of Polymer you're using so I will point you to the docs for Polymer 2 because that's what I use, but I am guessing something similar must exist for Polymer 3 also.

Any event triggered from elements rendered inside a dom-repeat will get a `model` key added, under which you will have the context, so you will have your `item` from HTML there.

You can see that in the docs [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/templates#handling-events).

To start you can try to:

```
_showTooltip: function(e) {
    var item = Polymer.dom(e).rootTarget;
    //........here I get Information out of my item to use it in my tooltip and display it
    console.log(e.model); debugger;
}
```

and continue from there..